# Compare Old Data with New Data in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new in Android Development and working on a project where I need to call an API after every one second, in that API there is field "Amount"(dBID) which keeps on changing, so I need to update the latest Amount (dBID) in recyclerview.

In order to do so, I have called this API in a service after every interval of one second.

The data is Showing Properly no Issue.

But for Now I need to perform some action on the Old Amount and New Amount.

Action Required : I need to compare the old value (dBID) with the New Value (dBID).

If the New Value is greater then I need to change the Text Color of Amount (dBID) to BLUE.

If the New Value is smaller then I need to change the Text Color of Amount (dBID) to RED.

Tried to achieve this by storing the old data in a Variable and then Comparing it to the new Value.

Issue : This logic is working fine until there are 5 or less Items in recyclerview as soon as the sixth item is added the same logic does not work.

Help me if anyone knows how I can achieve this.

For Example you can refer an App Vertexfx : Quotes Tab.

Below is the Code which I Tried.

Adapter class of the RecyclerView:

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <QuoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<QuoteData> data;

public QuoteAdapter(Context context,List<QuoteData> data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

 class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView time,symbol,sellmax,selllow,buymax,buylow,buy,sell,spread,lowtext,hightext;
    LinearLayout layout,layoutbid,layoutask;

    float currentbid,lastbid,currentask,lastask;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVTime);
        symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSymbol);
        sellmax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLMAX);
        selllow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLLOW);
        buymax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYMAX);
        buylow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYHIGH);
        buy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUY);
        sell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELL);
        spread = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSpread1);
        lowtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.low);
        hightext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.high);
        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layoutbid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLBid);
        layoutask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLAsk);
        currentbid = 0;
        lastbid = 0;
        currentask = 0;
        lastask = 0;
    }
}

 @NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quotelist,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    final QuoteData data1 = data.get(i);

    myViewHolder.time.setText(data1.dLut);
    myViewHolder.symbol.setText(data1.dSymbol);
    myViewHolder.sellmax.setText(data1.dBid);  //Bid
    myViewHolder.selllow.setText(data1.dLow);
    myViewHolder.buymax.setText(data1.dAsk);  //ask
    myViewHolder.buylow.setText(data1.dHigh);


    myViewHolder.currentbid = Float.parseFloat((data1.dBid));
    myViewHolder.currentask = Float.parseFloat((data1.dAsk));

    if (myViewHolder.currentbid > myViewHolder.lastbid)
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    if (myViewHolder.currentbid < myViewHolder.lastbid)
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    myViewHolder.lastbid = myViewHolder.currentbid;
    myViewHolder.lastask = myViewHolder.currentask;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: then simply maintain 2 list old and new and then compare object using id and check if amount is changed or not.

Comment: Thnx for the idea bro its working fine now.

Comment: welcome @Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future reference I have resolved the above mentioned issue using the below code.

Defined two ArrayList of String in Adapter

```
public class QuoteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <QuoteAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<QuoteData> data;
List<String> olddatabid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newdatabid = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> olddataask = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> newdataask = new ArrayList<String>();

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView time,symbol,sellmax,selllow,buymax,buylow,buy,sell,spread,lowtext,hightext;
    LinearLayout layout,layoutbid,layoutask;


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVTime);
        symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSymbol);
        sellmax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLMAX);
        selllow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELLLOW);
        buymax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYMAX);
        buylow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUYHIGH);
        buy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVBUY);
        sell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSELL);
        spread = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVSpread1);
        lowtext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.low);
        hightext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.high);
        layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layoutbid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLBid);
        layoutask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLAsk);
    }
}

public QuoteAdapter(Context context,List<QuoteData> data)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quotelist,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}


@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
    final QuoteData data1 = data.get(i);

    myViewHolder.time.setText(data1.dLut);
    myViewHolder.symbol.setText(data1.dSymbol);
    myViewHolder.sellmax.setText(data1.dBid);  //Bid
    myViewHolder.selllow.setText(data1.dLow);
    myViewHolder.buymax.setText(data1.dAsk);  //ask
    myViewHolder.buylow.setText(data1.dHigh);

    if (newdatabid.size()< data.size())
    {
        newdatabid.add(data1.dBid);  //Insert Value in array for the first time
    }

    if (olddatabid.size()< data.size())
    {
        olddatabid.add(data1.dBid);  //Insert Value in array for the first time
    }



    if (newdataask.size()< data.size())
    {
        newdataask.add(data1.dAsk);   //Insert Value in array for the first time
    }

    if (olddataask.size()< data.size())    //Insert Value in array for the first time
    {
        olddataask.add(data1.dAsk);
    }





    newdatabid.set(i,data1.dBid);   //Store Value in array
    newdataask.set(i,data1.dAsk);   //Store Value in array

    //Compare and perform Logic
    if (Float.valueOf(newdatabid.get(i)) > Float.valueOf(olddatabid.get(i)))
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    if (Float.valueOf(newdatabid.get(i)) < Float.valueOf(olddatabid.get(i)))
    {
        myViewHolder.sellmax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }



    if (Float.valueOf(newdataask.get(i)) > Float.valueOf(olddataask.get(i)))
    {
        myViewHolder.buymax.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    if (Float.valueOf(newdataask.get(i)) < Float.valueOf(olddataask.get(i)))
    {
        myViewHolder.buymax.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }


    olddatabid.set(i,newdatabid.get(i));
    olddataask.set(i,newdataask.get(i));

            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at those classes from the Android SDK:

- [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil)
- [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer)
- [ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)

**DiffUtil**

`DiffUtil` is designed to compare existing and new recycler view items and fires appropriate events. You need to pass a callback that can tell if two items are the same and if their content has changed.

**AsyncListDiffer**

It wraps the `DiffUtil` and executes it's logic asynchronously, giving better performance.

**ItemAnimator**

The `ItemAnimator` for a given `RecyclerView` is called by default when change events are fired on it's items. You can provide an implementation of the `animateChange` method to change your color accordingly.

Comment: Thnx for the reference bro...
I'll check the above points as well if i can do the same with these classes.